How can I reuse a SeleniumBase driver instance across multiple scripts in UC (Undetected Chrome) mode?
I'm currently using SeleniumBase with UC mode to launch a web page. After starting a browser instance in one script, I would like to reuse that instance in another script within the same project. However, when I attempt to do this, a new browser window opens instead of reusing the existing one.
Is there a way to continue using the same driver instance across different scripts without launching a new browser? Any guidance or best practices for achieving this would be greatly appreciated.
Here's a snippet of my code:
from seleniumbase import Driver
from time import sleep

my_user_dir = "C:/ProgramData/Midbots/User Data/Chrome Data"
url = "https://www.midddleman.co/"


def launch_driver():
    # ############ LAUNCH BROWSER ############
    driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=None, user_data_dir=my_user_dir, disable_gpu=True)
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 5)
    driver.uc_gui_click_captcha()
    sleep(5)

    return driver

launch_driver()

I want to keep working with the same webpage in another script using the existing driver instance without opening a new browser. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
